# Return value in MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, dom, callback, dom-manipulation, mutation-observers

I'm struggling to `return` a value in my code below.

- I'm watching `document.querySelector('[search-model="pod"]')` and waiting for a button, in it's childlist to appear/disappear.
- Where the `mutations[i].oldValue === "button ng-hide"` exists, this is when the button appears in the DOM.
- I've specifically used `MutationObserver`, as this button appears, disappears and appears multiple times. And each time I need to `return` a value, like `true`.

This is why I haven't used promises, as the promise only resolves the first time.  And not for all reoccuring times, the button appears.

I've really been struggling with this and I don't work with any other developers at work.  Any ideas, on how I can amend this code, to `return true`, every time the buttons appears?

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        if (mutations[i].oldValue === "button ng-hide") {
            console.log("Button is appearing...");
        };
    };

});

let target = document.querySelector('[search-model="pod"]');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeOldValue: true, subtree: true});
```

Comment: The return value of the callback function isn't used. The function should just make the DOM changes that you want.

Comment: You can't return values asynchronously unless you use a promise or async/await.

Comment: Why do you think you need to return a value? What is the overall goal?

Comment: I’m building an AB Test via Optimise 360 and in order to trigger my test, the tool requests for a value to be returned. So I have to return a value, every time the button appears, to trigger the AB Test.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this without using mutation observer? Promises only return the value fire time round. Would this also be the case with async/await

Comment: Whatever you do will run asynchronously so it doesn't make sense to return a value.

Comment: "promises only return the value first time round" -- you have to create a new promise when the previous one resolves, and then wait for that.

Comment: It becomes easier if you use async/await, then you can write a loop.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks Barmar. Do you have an example, I could use/look at?